# Plotting a set of parametric equations using only points

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am using `ParametricPlot3D` to plot a superellipsoid using the code below:

```
    Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{
        a1 Sign[Cos[eta] Cos[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Cos[omega]]^e2,
        a2 Sign[Cos[eta] Sin[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Sin[omega]]^e2,
        a3 Sign[Sin[eta]] Abs[Sin[eta]]^e1}, {eta, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {omega, -Pi, Pi}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False],
       {a1, 0.1, 2}, {a2, 0.1, 2}, {a3, 0.1, 2}, {e1, 0.1, 1.9}, {e2, 0.1, 1.9}]
```

However I now need to plot just the `(x,y,z)` triplets generated using samples of `eta, omega` in their respective ranges, and given some constant values for the rest of the parameters `a1,a2,a3,e1,e2`. Unfortunately I only recently started using mathematica and I am unfamiliar with its mechanics. From the docs I could not find an option for `ParametricPlot3D` to plot just the points.

My goal here is to be able to plot the resulting points, using different distributions of `eta, omega`. I tried splitting the parametric plot into 3 separate functions:

```
    X (eta_, omega_, a1_, e1_, e2_) := a1 Sign[Cos[eta] Cos[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Cos[omega]]^e2
    Y (eta_, omega_, a2_, e1_, e2_) := a2 Sign[Cos[eta] Sin[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Sin[omega]]^e2
    Z (eta_, omega_, a3_, e1_, e2_) := a3 Sign[Sin[eta]] Abs[Sin[eta]]^e1

    eta = Subdivide[-Pi/2, Pi/2, 50]
    omega = Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 50]
```

Then I planned use `eta, omega` as inputs to get the `x,y,z` outputs. However functions don't seem to take ranges as input, and also I would prefer a solution I can use `Manipulate` on, to control the values of `a1,a2,a3,e1,e2` separately. How should I go about this?

Comment: `X (eta_, omega_, a1_, e1_, e2_)` this is not correct syntax - it should be `X[eta_, omega_, a1_, e1_, e2_] := ...` . You could either generate random numbers, or use a `Table` for the points as follows `ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Table[..., {eta, -Pi/2, Pi/2, .025}, {omega, -Pi, Pi, .025}],1]]`

Comment: @flinty So instead of `...` I put my 3 functions `X,Y,Z`? Will `Manipulate` with `a1,a2,a3,e1,e2` work?

Comment: If you with to plot a set of points in 3D, use `ListPointPlot3D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**despite is not that clear that do you want to manipulate the Points as Well!!? or only Plot!? or both !?**

**Here is my answer**

```
x[eta_, omega_, a1_, e1_, e2_] := 
 a1 Sign[Cos[eta] Cos[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Cos[omega]]^e2

y[eta_, omega_, a2_, e1_, e2_] := 
 a2 Sign[Cos[eta] Sin[omega]] Abs[Cos[eta]]^e1 Abs[Sin[omega]]^e2

z[eta_, omega_, a3_, e1_, e2_] := a3 Sign[Sin[eta]] Abs[Sin[eta]]^e1


Manipulate[
 Show[
  {
   ListPointPlot3D[
    Table[{x[eta, omega, a1, e1, e2], y[eta, omega, a2, e1, e2], 
      z[eta, omega, a3, e1, e2]}, {eta, -Pi/2, Pi/2, .1}, {omega, -Pi,
       Pi, .1}], PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Red}],
   
   ParametricPlot3D[{x[eta, omega, a1, e1, e2], 
     y[eta, omega, a2, e1, e2], 
     z[eta, omega, a3, e1, e2]}, {eta, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {omega, -Pi, Pi},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]]]
   }
  
  , Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
 , {a1, 0.1, 2}, {a2, 0.1, 2}, {a3, 0.1, 2}, {e1, 0.1, 1.9}, {e2, 0.1,
   1.9}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if the question was unclear, I only started using it 2 days ago. I have two questions, is there a way to have a slider controlling the amount of `eta` and `omega` samples? Also, if I wanted to use a different distribution of `eta,omega`, can I generate it separately and replace `{eta, -Pi/2, Pi/2, .1}` ?